# Can I pass optional props to a component in Vuejs so they are passed to a component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some recurring calls to a component from different views, such as:

```html
<highcharts
    :options="getSomeData"
    :constructor-type="'mapChart'"
    :callback="getSomeDataCallback"
    class="someFancyStyle"                                                        
/>
```

Since it is within a more general block that loads data and controls the errors, I have created a new component "GraphDisplay" to handle this:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="loading"> loading... </div>
        <div v-else-if="error"> error... </div>

        <div v-else>
            <div v-if="highcharts">
                <highcharts
                        :options="data"
                />
            </div>
            <div v-else>
                <slot></slot>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "GraphDisplay",
    props: {
        loading: Object,
        error: Object,
        data: Object,
        highcharts: Boolean,
    },
};
</script>
```

So now I have to just call GraphDisplay with:

```html
<GraphDisplay
        :loading="bla.isLoading"
        :error="bla.errors"
        :data="bla.data"
        highcharts
/>
```

or

```html
<GraphDisplay
        :loading="bla.isLoading"
        :error="bla.errors"
>
     <another graph>
</GraphDisplay>
```

This works well.

The thing now is that `<highcharts>` sometimes has more than one prop, as seen in the first code I posted here: it may have "constructor-type", "callback", "class", or others.

Is there a way to pass props that are optional, so they are *used* when calling the component? I tried passing a new prop "config" and feed with possible values:

```js
    props: {
        loading: Object,
        error: Object,
        data: Object,
        highcharts: Boolean,
        config: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => {}
        },
    },
```

So the call is like this:

```html
<GraphDisplay
        :loading="getSomeData.isLoading"
        :error="getSomeData.errors"
        :data="getSomeData.data"
        :config="{
                    constructorType: 'mapChart',
                    class: 'someFancyStyle'
                }"
/>
```

And the component uses it as follows:

```html
<highcharts
    :options="data"
    :constructor-type="config.constructorType"
    :class="config.class"
>
```

However, things seem to be overly complicated and I don't know if this is the path to follow. All I would like is to have a set of props marked as *optional* that get *delivered* to `<highcharts>` in case they are provided. I think in the [Spread syntax `{ ... }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) so I could say:

```html
<div v-if="highcharts">
    <highcharts
            :options="data"
            ...config // adding extra data here
    />
</div>
```

Comment: Props are optional by default. In order to make them required you have to specifically declare it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semantics in your example, where multiple props from an object are bound at once, indeed exists in Vue with the [`v-bind` (without an argument)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) directive.

In this case, `v-bind="config"` binds all properties from `config` to the component. Non-applicable props from `config` would be bound as HTML attributes (visible upon inspecting the element from DevTools), or as properties otherwise. If `config` is empty, no bindings would occur.

Assuming the `config` value below:

```js
const config = {
  nonExistentProp: 'foo',
  constructorType: 'mapChart',
  class: 'someFancyStyle',
}
```

The following template:

```html
<highcharts v-bind="config" />
```

would be equivalent to:

```html
<highcharts nonexistentprop="foo" class="someFancyStyle" constructor-type="mapChart" />
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/binding-multiple-props-with-v-bind-in-vue-6x71j?file=/src/components/GraphDisplay.vue)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot, I am happy to see I was almost there :) You are very kind to provide a very detailed with even a fiddle to test, it's been very useful and now I have it up and running.